# How can I change MUI v5 Button to lighten on hover instead of darken using theme?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have setup my theme as outlined in the docs.

```
palette: {
    primary: {
        main: customColor
    }
}
```

When I hover, my mui button darkens based on the main color, but I want it to lighten based on the same color (without having to hard code a value anywhere). How can I achieve this?

Update:
Based on Prashant Jangam's answer I was able to get everything exactly as I needed it. See code below:

```
components: {
        MuiButton: {
            styleOverrides: {
                root: ({ theme }) => ({
                    '&.MuiButton-containedPrimary:hover': {
                        backgroundColor: theme.palette.primary.light,
                    },
                    '&.MuiButton-containedSecondary:hover': {
                        backgroundColor: theme.palette.secondary.light,
                    },
                }),
            },
        },
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

check the global component overide section for more details https://mui.com/customization/theme-components/#global-style-overrides

following code with give you start. here I have changed opacity on button hover state.

```
const theme = createTheme({
  // your other theme settings here
  components: {
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: ({ ownerState }) => ({
          '&:hover': {
            opacity:0.5,
          },
        }),
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

At least on the version 4 of MUI the **palette.primary.dark** is the color that is used for hovering the button. Just replace the value of the dark property with the value that you want (hex color or rgb/rgba).

***Note:** It can also change some hovering colors on another components*

```
 const baseTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
     primary: {
      main: '#4B882F',
      dark: '#345F20', // <-------- rgba(75, 136, 47, 0.2)
      light: '#6F9F58'
     }
   }
 })
```

You can't use it like this because the baseTheme was not defined yet.

```
const baseTheme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
     primary: {
      main: '#4B882F',
      dark: baseTheme.palette.primary.light,
      light: '#6F9F58'
     }
   }
 })
```

Answer (score 0):

I customize it like so:

```
 const theme = createTheme({
  get components() {
    return {
      MuiButton: {
        styleOverrides: {
          root: ({ ownerState }) => ({
            '&:hover': {
              backgroundColor: this.palette[ownerState.color].light,
              transition: '0.2s',
            },
          }),
        },
      },
    }
  },
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: '#3E4BA0',
      dark: '#313b7d',
      light: '#5664bd',
    },

  },

})
```